# Publish Images without TCMUri across publications

Tags: publishing

I have a requirement to publish images without TCMUri across multiple publications, so we don't get duplicate images with different TcmUris across different sites/Pubs, all these images should reside in one physical folder.

After modifying the binary publisher TBB, we got an undesirable side-effect. if someone un-publish an asset that used to depend on an image from one publication, the image will be un-published/Deleted , and hence other sites will loose that particular image.

My Question is there a way to disable un-publishing unused binary. I tried a way to publish images in an unmanaged way , that did the trick but that method was deprecated from the API, and I don't want to use it in my code. Any Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide some more details about the Tridion Version You are using. Because What I have understand, you want to manage the images in central repository. I think in that case you should use SDL Media Manager where you can directly use the CDN url of the image in your component.

Comment: Thank you @SayantanBasu for your comment, we are running Tridion 2013 Sp1. and Yes I am aware of the Tridion ability to connect to an external content library such as Media Manager. its just not in the the scope of my project.

Comment: I guess you'd have to create a Binary Storage extension, and make sure the files are not deleted when unpublishing. You will run into trouble at some point, when that one PDF really needs to be unpublished... but your editors can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Whenever any item is unpublished, deployer checks for multimedia items associated with the item being unpublished in Reference_Entries table and if no other references are found then it will remove those multimedia assets.

In your case, since you have modified the behavior to have only one multimedia component across all publications, the check done by deployer will not yield any result and the multimedia items will be deleted.

Can you please provide details on your blueprint hierarchy and at which levels have you enabled publishing, this information will help us identify appropriate approach for your situation?